# How to remove script tags

Tags: file, tags

I have loaded many script files:

Eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" script file "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" script file "></script>

$('button').on('click', function() {
   $('script').remove(); // but the script events are still functioning.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the script is already loaded, then you cannot un-load it. Removing the `<script>` tag from the page won't have any effect.

A better option: An event handler or event listener [can be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15100576/3345375) using jQuery's `.off()` function or JavaScript's `removeEventListener()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a link to jquery.js, or use the CDN and write code in a script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('button').on('click', function() {
     $('script').remove(); // but the script events are still functioning.
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like the right answer to the wrong question... The original poster's question wasn't "how do I load jQuery," but rather "how do I cancel or remove an event handler that I previously attached to an element."

Comment: @jkdev you are right bro, do you have any ideas about that? I still haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: If you want to un-bind an event listener, [you can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36709423/3345375). If you want to un-load the script itself, [you cannot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34997399/3345375).